# pdf to jpg : can't recognize file

Tags: pdf, jpeg

When i run :

from pdf2jpg import pdf2jpg

PATH = "C:/Users/yyyyyy/Desktop/test_ocr/data"

pdf2jpg.convert_pdf2jpg(PATH +"/" + 'xxxx.pdf',PATH +"/results", pages = "ALL")

I get this error:

[WinError 2] Le fichier spécifié est introuvable

Though I'm sure that this file exists. What should I do to make it work ?

Comment: Try to use paths with backslash instead of forward slash. While forward slashes work in Python, they do not universally work in Java. (pdf2jpg is mainly written in Java with a thin Python binding that doesn't clean up filenames.)

Comment: tried both , but it still doesn't work

Comment: update : it works from python and not from a notebook

Comment: i changed my version of jupyter and the path is recognized now :)